# add custom shortcut to eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I do a lot of javascript stuff with eclipse, so "console.log()" is my friend.

is there a way to tell eclipse to insert "console.log()" on a shortcut like cmd + shift + c (e.g.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a custom shortcut. How about this:

1. Preference -> JavaScript -> Editor -> Templates -> New

   `Name:     log

   Pattern:  console.log()`
2. Click [OK]
3. Open js file
4. Type `l`
5. Use Short cut command for Content Assist(Dialog appears)
6. Select `log`
7. It will insert `console.log()` on editor